# expectk in Debian 9

Tags: expect

I am reading the book "Why programs fail" from Andreas Zeller. It has exercises that requires using the Android automation tool (not to be confused with Google's OS). I could download it from the author's website but when I started the android file as described in the user's guide I got the following error:

```
bash: ./android: /usr/bin/expectk: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install expectk:

```
sudo apt-get install expectk
```

But I got the error message:

```
E: Package 'expectk' has no installation candidate.
```

**The question is: How can I install this expectk to make Android work?**
I am working on Debian 9.

Comment: https://linuxappfinder.com/package/expectk

Answer (score 7):

`expectk` was dropped from Expect in version 5.45. [`NEWS.Debian`](https://salsa.debian.org/tcltk-team/expect/blob/master/debian/NEWS) gives possible workarounds:

> As of Expect 5.45 `expectk` was removed from the upstream distribution     and from the Debian package as well. If you're using `expectk` replace it     either by `expect` and `package require Tk` or by `wish` and     `package require Expect`.

You need to install the `expect` package and adapt the `android` script as described above.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the shebang of android to #!/usr/bin/expect. I added a line: package require Tk. Now I get a different error: Can't find package android while executing "package require android". And the menumgr packages is also missing. I tried copying the files mentioned in android-0.99.9.spec to /usr/local/bin and to /usr/bin but this had no effect.